# Non-existent file being served by apache

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

Let's say I have a domain called www.example.com

Within the root of this domain i have a few HTML files (index.html, blogs.html, info.html)

Navigating to any of the files works (www.example.com/blogs)

For some reason though, `www.example.com/blogs/somerandomtext` also seems to go to the same file

Why does this still load the page and can I set this to redirect to a 404 error page.

My domain is hosted using Apache and I have a .htaccess file which is below.

Any help?

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ - [F,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

ErrorDocument 400 http://www.example.com/error
ErrorDocument 403 http://www.example.com/error
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/error
ErrorDocument 500 http://www.example.com/error

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rules are unconditionally rewriting every non-existent file to `.php` and then rewriting `/anything` to `/anything.html`.

Check for existence of corresponding `.php` or `.html` files before adding those extensions in your rules.

```
Options -MultiViews
CheckSpelling off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ - [F,NC]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: I've implemented your code above but I can still navigate to `www.example.com/blog/somethingrandom` the address bar stays as that but shows the contents of `www.example.com/blogs` I need this to be sent to `example.com/error`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear before. I don't have a `blogs` directory. I only have a `blogs.php` file and a `blog` directory. There are no other htaccess files.

Comment: After adding the `Options -MultiViews` line at the top any page other than the root path redirects to `error` and this causes a redirect loop.

Comment: sorry i was wrong before. domain.com/info goes to /error. domain.com/info.html does not.

Comment: the .htaccess file is located in the root of the domain. So the directory that `www.example.com` points at.

Comment: Now going to `domain.com/info` give me a 300 status code and shows a `Multiple Choices` web page because `info` couldn't be found on the server. It suggest `info.html` but doesn't redirect automatically.

Comment: Now going to `domain.com/info` sends me to `domain.com/error` but its a redirect loop again

Comment: You have some strange problem in your Apache config that is not making those rewrite rules work. btw it works fine on my Apache

Comment: Ok. I'll ring my hosting provider and see if they can help.